# Errors trying to set fuses on bare Atmega328p

Tags: atmega328, avrdude, oscillator-clock, fuses

I have an Atmega328p on a board that I want to program using an Arduino programmer. I've got the programmer working to program other Arduino's over ICSP header, but when trying to use the same settings to avrdude to read/set the fuses of the bare MCU with oscillator I get the following:

```
❯❯❯ avrdude -v -p atmega328p -b 19200 -P /dev/cu.wchusbserial213240 -c stk500v1                                                                                                          ⏎ master

avrdude: Version 6.3, compiled on Sep 18 2017 at 20:31:51
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "/usr/local/Cellar/avrdude/6.3/etc/avrdude.conf"
         User configuration file is "/Users/viktor/.avrduderc"
         User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping

         Using Port                    : /dev/cu.wchusbserial213240
         Using Programmer              : stk500v1
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 19200
         AVR Part                      : ATmega328P
         Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us
         PAGEL                         : PD7
         BS2                           : PC2
         RESET disposition             : dedicated
         RETRY pulse                   : SCK
         serial program mode           : yes
         parallel program mode         : yes
         Timeout                       : 200
         StabDelay                     : 100
         CmdexeDelay                   : 25
         SyncLoops                     : 32
         ByteDelay                     : 0
         PollIndex                     : 3
         PollValue                     : 0x53
         Memory Detail                 :

                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           eeprom        65    20     4    0 no       1024    4      0  3600  3600 0xff 0xff
           flash         65     6   128    0 yes     32768  128    256  4500  4500 0xff 0xff
           lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
           signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

         Programmer Type : STK500
         Description     : Atmel STK500 Version 1.x firmware
         Hardware Version: 2
         Firmware Version: 1.18
         Topcard         : Unknown
         Vtarget         : 0.0 V
         Varef           : 0.0 V
         Oscillator      : Off
         SCK period      : 0.1 us

avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.08s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x000000 (retrying)

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.08s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x000000 (retrying)

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.08s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x000000
avrdude: Yikes!  Invalid device signature.
         Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
         this check.


avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

I've checked the soldering as good as I can and it seems to be right. I have a 10K pullup on reset, an oscillator with caps. I'm suspecting I might have fried the MCU when soldering or something - is there anything simple I can check?

- All PWR connections check out
- I've checked the oscillator with a scope and it isn't oscillating, but I'm thinking that is normal since it's a bare chip that I'm trying to set the fuses to use the external crystal? The oscillator is at least connected correctly.

Comment: Try using the "burn bootloader" function inside the IDE. That also sets the fuses.

Comment: I've done that too. The first thing that menu item does though is actually calling avrdude just like that - I think I actually looked at the verbose log in the IDE to get the params right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out it was a bit of bad soldering on the MCU. This same msg you'll get if just leaving the ICSP floating.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution, but could you accept this (your own) answer as the solution?
This question just got bumped to the frontpage and actually is already solved.